# Как выводить подпись картинки вместе с ней на экран?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace Antonov
{
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    Image image;
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Size = new Size(1530, 850);
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1530, 850);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1530, 850);
          
    } 




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        
        OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openDialog.Filter = "Файлы изображений|*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg";
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        try
        {
            image = Image.FromFile(openDialog.FileName);
        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка чтения картинки");
            return;
        }
        
        panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = image.Size;
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        
        panel1.Size = new Size(1244, 650);
        if (image == null)
            return;

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(
            image,
            panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X,
            panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y,
            image.Size.Width,
            image.Size.Height

            
        );

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form3 temp = new Form3();
        temp.Region = this.Region;
        temp.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.antonov.com/");
    }
}
```

}

Есть галерея, где пользователь может выбрать фото из папки и вывести его на экран, хотелось бы чтоб вместе с фоткой выводилось и название картинки которое указано в файле.

Answer (score 0):

В panel1_Paint добавьте `e.Graphics.DrawString("название картинки", font, brush, point_position)` после DrawImage.

Comment: Работает, но хотелось чтоб выводилась не моя подпись которую я напишу а название картинки которое в папке подписано.

Comment: @user434841 ну так подставляйте туда имя файла, изображение само по себе имя не хранит.